# Cannot import/use packages in Python

Tags: dataframe, import, pip, path, package

I'm aware that this question has been asked before, but after doing quite a bit of research, I find myself stuck with my problem.

I'm currently comfortable in R, and would like to gradually learn Python basics. I've installed python from the official website, and opted for the Spyder IDE. I ran a few basic Python commands such a printing hello. So far so good. Now I'd like to learn by working with datasets.

My understanding is that you need the Pandas package for that (or it is at least recommended). And here start the many, many issues. I read that you need pip to install packages. To my surprise, I had to install that through the windows command prompt. After many failed attempts, I managed, and later even managed installing the packages. However, when I go back to the Spyder IDE and try to run the generic commands, it always returns invalid syntax to me.

I'm happy to share screenshots, or more details if the problem isn't clear enough. I expected to find a steep learning curve at the very beginning, but not to struggle with packages.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, please share screenshots or outputs of the command prompt.  Also how did you install `pandas`? The recommended method would be `pip install pandas` (considering you are using windows)

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer. I ended up solving my problem. Essentially, when I would install an IDE like Pycharm, I didn't select the python version I had installed on my PC. So even though I installed packages through the cmd with pip, it would still tell me that I don't have that package installed. I changed to using my local python version and now everything works fine.

Comment: Good to know your issue was resolved! I would recommend that use code editors like "Sublime Text" or "VS Code" as they are simpler. PyCharm is quite advanced and offers robust features and complex methods to use them, it may be overwhelming to people starting with the language.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at those. I've also been trying my luck with Jupyter Notebooks, quite enjoying the format tbh.

Comment: Of course,  Jupyter is great.  Just noted some of my preferrences.  Whatever works for you.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks for all the tips